# I don't know how it work table[+1]?

Tags: c++

My beginer friend do this code and i don't know how its can work for example this table[+1]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    int tablica[100];
    for (tablica[0]=1;tablica[a]<=100;tablica[+1]){
        cout << tablica[a] << endl;
        tablica[a]+=1;
    }

}
```

Comment: This code invokes **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No it doesn't.  `tablica[0]` is incremented until it exceeds 100 and then the program finishes

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop like:

```
for (init; test; repeat) {
    body;
}
```

is mostly equivalent to:

```
init;
while (test) {
    body;
    repeat;
}
```

So the loop you're given is like:

```
tablica[0]=1;
while (tablica[a] <= 100) {
    cout << tablica[a] << endl;
    tablica[a] += 1;
    tablica[+1];
}
```

Since `a` was initialized to `0`, and is never changed, `tablica[a]` is the same as `tablica[0]`.

`tablica[+1]` is executed, but it never uses the value of that array element. The array element is not initialized, so its value is indeterminate, but since the value isn't used for anything it's not a problem. You can just ignore that part of it (and the compiler will most likely optimize it away).

So this isn't really much different from a typical loop like:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Your friend was just trying to confuse you (and succeeding) by using an array element instead of a simple variable for the iteration, and throwing in the extraneous expression `tablica[+1]` that looks kind of like iteration, but doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Note, there is no attempt to access the stored value of `tablica[1]`  . In C++ discarded-value expressions do not undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion

Answer (score 0):

`a` is always 0, so `tablica[0]` and `tablica[a]` are always the same thing.

`for (tablica[0]=1;`, now we have initialised `tablica[0]` to 1.

`tablica[a]<=100;`, this will break when `tablica[0]` is greater than 100.

`tablica[a]+=1;`, it is actually being incremented in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

It simply cout `tablica[0]` but 100 times (starting from 1 2 3 .. 100), each time incrementing `tablica[0]`. Variable `a` is never changed. 
At `for` where is `tablica[+1]` is equal to `tablica[1]`, but it simply get value from it and don't do any thing with it.

Comment: `tablica[1]` is not initialised, so technically evaluating this expression invokes UB.  As pointed out in another answer, this will typically be optimised to a no-op by the compiler, but there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: This was correct until the very end... it does not even get value from `tablica[1]`. That expression just does nothing. (And does not cause UB).

Comment: @M.M - An optimising compiler may choose not to get the value, but there's nothing in the standard that mandates that.  Indeed Annex J of C99 states that it's UB to use the value of an indeterminate object, so I guess it depends on whether "use" includes "evaluation" :)  But the specific badness I'm imagining is this loading a trap representation into a register, thus causing an error.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth C99 annex J is irrelevant to C++. There is something in the C++ standard that mandates to not get the value.

Comment: @M.M. the fact that this question is C++ is (a) something I didn't spot and (b) a good argument for why that annex is irrelevant ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You are right, there is UB for not initialised array. I suppose it will return current memory value. I have "fixed" my replay.